# /usr/bin/updatedb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: 16.04, binary, updatedb

I am trying to build TensorFlow 1.6. in a Nvidia Jetson TX2, using a script located in: https://github.com/JasonAtNvidia/JetsonTFBuild/blob/master/BuildTensorflow.sh

In this script, "updatedb" is invoked (line 96) and I have a problem at this moment:
`BuildTensorflow.sh: line 96: /usr/bin/updatedb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

`$ sudo updatedb 
/usr/bin/updatedb: 1: /usr/bin/updatedb: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Maybe these information can help;

```
$ sudo apt-get install mlocate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mlocate:i386 is already the newest version (0.26-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get install locate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
locate:i386 is already the newest version (4.6.0+git+20160126-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils
locate:i386: /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils

$ dpkg --print-architecture
arm64

$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main 
restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted 
universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial- 
security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial- 
updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial- 
proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial- 
backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main 
restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main 
restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main 
restricted universe multiverse 

$ head -n1 /etc/nv_tegra_release
# R28 (release), REVISION: 2.0, GCID: 10567845, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: 
aarch64, DATE: Fri Mar  2 04:57:01 UTC 2018
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I really do not know how to solve this problem, any help/lead is appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!